# The Data windows keeps disapearing after a syntax is performed

Tags: spss

Every time I run a syntax that creates a new data set, the Data Editor windows returns to background. It is still there, but not visible so that it is necessary to Alt-Tab to that windows. Try for example

```
data list list
  /x.

begin data
1
2
3
end data.
```

Although it does not hamper SPSS capabilities, it is very annoying as I prefer to see the results after every suntax performed. Also, I try to teach SPSS to undergrad students. So I have to explain them that there command worked but the result is not visible (for god knows what reason).

Is it possible to change this default behavior? Or is there a simple syntax that would bring back the Data Editor up front and visible? (if it may help, I have python extensions installed, but the library wx is not functionnal).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the possibility to set such a default behaviour, but I am using this way to assign a name to the dataset and then manipulate its behaviour.

```
dataset name SomeName window=front.
```

In theory, once the dataset has a name, the same should be achieved by using:

```
dataset activate SomeName window=front.
```

nut I never got this to work - it never brings it to front.

I find the dataset commands very useful when dealing with multiple datasets at the same time, in order to make sure each piece of syntax is being run on the intended dataset:

`DATASET NAME, DATASET ACTIVATE, DATASET DECLARE, DATASET COPY, DATASET CLOSE` - see the actual SPSS help entries for each of them

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. I knew about these commands and they were not effective in SPSS 19. Right now, testing your commands using SPSS 22, it does seem to work! Can anyone confirm?